# Parsing argument with JSF commandlink to managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, commandlink

I tried to parse argument with JSF to managed bean with ajax. my JSF code is this

```
        <h:commandLink id="user" action="#{pageBean.setPage("user")}" >
                                    user
                   <f:ajax execute="user" render="contentBody" />

       </h:commandLink>
```

managed bean is this

```
@ManagedBean
public class PageBean {
    private String path;
    private String page;

    public PageBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public  void init(){
        path = "/WEB-INF/dashboard.xhtml";
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
 }
```

But when I run this I got following error. Why is that?

```
Error Parsing /WEB-INF/templete.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 37] Element type "h:commandLink" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using double quotes in your attribute around `user`.

```
<h:commandLink id="user" action="#{pageBean.setPage("user")}" >
```

This results in `templete.xml` not beeing a valid XML-File.

Correct example line using single quotes (as proposed by @gWombat):

```
<h:commandLink id="user" action="#{pageBean.setPage('user')}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple quotes around the parameter *user*:

```
action="#{pageBean.setPage('user')}"
```